Хочу сдкелать ближний бой в unity 3d , но нечего не работает хотя ошибок нет , что делать
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class touch : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        
        
        if (collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Control>( ))
        {    
            
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
            {
                hpvraga.health -= 1;
                Debug.Log(hpvraga.health);




            }



        }
    }
}


GetComponent<Transform>().position и transform.position - это одно и то же, поэтому будет ноль.
